# Powerapp security or privilege question

Tags: sharepoint-online, powerapps-forms

I have developed few powerapp standalone forms. Will anyone from the organization able to interact with the form or they must have license? these are HR forms.

Scenario 2: I have few sharepoint lists and libraries where I like to make changes to out of the box edit form by using powerapps. Do end users need to have powerapp license to use these forms ?

I wonder if there is like a good matrix of these type of situation.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, a standalone Power Apps plan license is required to access all Premium, on-premises and custom connectors.

If a user doesn’t have any Power Apps licenses, the only sign-up option for individual users in your organization is the Power Apps trial, for which they can sign up through the Power Apps website:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/power-platform/admin/signup-question-and-answer#sign-up-for-power-apps

And for the [customized SharePoint list form by PowerApps](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/maker/canvas-apps/customize-list-form#requirements), check as following:

[image]

Comment: If you find any answer helpful to you, please remember to accept it as answer.

Thank you for your understanding.